# how to validate react formik form depending on the input content?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I need to validate the form as follows: all fields in the form are optional, but if at least one field has a value entered, they all become mandatory.

I wrote:

```
const getRequiredSchema = () => {
   return Yup.string().when(["full_name", "email", "password"], {
     is: (...args) => args.some((item) => !!item),
     then: Yup.string().required("Required!")
   });
 };
...
validationSchema: Yup.object({
      full_name: getRequiredSchema(),
      email: getRequiredSchema(),
      password: getRequiredSchema()
})
```

And got an error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"password"
OK, I rewrote the code, trying to get rid of looping:

```
const getRequiredSchema = (field) => {
  return Yup.string().when(
    ["full_name", "email", "password"].filter((f) => f !== field),
    {
      is: (...args) => args.some((item) => !!item),
      then: Yup.string().required("Required!")
    }
  );
};
....
validationSchema: Yup.object({
      full_name: getRequiredSchema("full_name"),
      email: getRequiredSchema("email"),
      password: getRequiredSchema("password")
})
```

But the error did not disappear. How to write validation correctly?
Here is the [full cole on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-yup-forked-fmgxzl?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please mark the accepted answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, If you want to stick with Yup, one workaround could be to remove the circular dependency by creating a custom validation function that checks if at least one field has a value.

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const validationSchema = (values) => {
  return Yup.object().shape({
    full_name: values.email || values.password ? Yup.string().required("Required") : Yup.string(),
    email: values.full_name || values.password ? Yup.string().required("Required") : Yup.string(),
    password: values.full_name || values.email ? Yup.string().required("Required") : Yup.string()
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      full_name: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    },
    validationSchema: () => validationSchema(formik.values),
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Full Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="full_name"
            maxLength="10"
            value={formik.values.full_name}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          />
          {formik.errors.full_name && formik.touched.full_name && (
            <p>{formik.errors.full_name}</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formik.values.email}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          />
          {formik.errors.email && formik.touched.email && (
            <p>{formik.errors.email}</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formik.values.password}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          />
          {formik.errors.password && formik.touched.password && (
            <p>{formik.errors.password}</p>
          )}
        </div>

        <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **Yup Lazy**

```
const validationSchema = Yup.lazy((values) => {
  const {full_name, email, password} = values
  if (full_name || email || password) {
    return Yup.object().shape({
      full_name: Yup.string().required(),
      email: Yup.string().required(),
      password: Yup.string().required(),
    })
  }
  return Yup.mixed().notRequired()
})
```

I have fixed your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-yup-forked-s6w7y3?file=/src/App.js